# reduce margins for figure with subfigures

Tags: graphics, margins

I have a figure with 4 subfigures like the following

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
 \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.49\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{1}
   \caption{1}
  \end{subfigure}
   \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.49\textwidth}
   \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{2}
  \caption{2}
  \end{subfigure}
   \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.49\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{3}
    \caption{3}
  \end{subfigure}
   \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.49\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{4}
    \caption{4}
 \end{subfigure}
\caption{blabla}
\end{figure}
```

and I'd like to reduce the margins (right and left) just for this figure (that means that the image should be larger than the text).

I've tried to increase the textwidth with the geometry environment but it seems to affect the whole page, putting all that is after the `\restoregeometry` in the next page.

```
\newgeometry{textwidth=18cm}
\restoregeometry
```

Comment: This has come up before.   The solution is to overlap the margins in a way that doesn't cause error messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean like this?

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\begin{document}
\blindtext
\begin{figure}[h]
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.46\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=1.1\linewidth,center]{1}
        \caption{1}
    \end{subfigure}\hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.46\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=1.1\linewidth,center]{2}
        \caption{2}
    \end{subfigure}%

    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.46\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=1.1\linewidth,center]{3}
        \caption{3}
    \end{subfigure}\hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.46\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=1.1\linewidth,center]{4}
        \caption{4}
    \end{subfigure}%
    \caption{blabla}
\end{figure}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

For a local change of margins, use `changepage` and its `adjustwidth` environment.

For setting the width of the subfigures, use `\linewidth` as appropriate in a `list` based environment, which `adjustwidth` is. For the width of the images in the subfigures, use `\textwidth`, that refers to the subfigure's stated width.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{changepage}

\begin{document}

\blindtext

\begin{figure}[htp]
\begin{adjustwidth}{-1cm}{-1cm}
\centering

\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.49\linewidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
  \caption{1}
\end{subfigure}\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.49\linewidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
  \caption{2}
\end{subfigure}

\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.49\linewidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
  \caption{3}
\end{subfigure}\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.49\linewidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
  \caption{4}
\end{subfigure}

\end{adjustwidth}

\caption{blabla}

\end{figure}

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To take the magic out:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{showframe}

\newenvironment{widespace}[1]% #1 = width
{\dimen0=#1\relax% only one error message for bad #1
 \dimen1=\dimexpr 0.5\dimen0 - 0.5\textwidth\relax
 \hspace*{-\dimen1}\minipage{\dimen0}}%
{\endminipage\hspace{-\dimen1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{widespace}{6in}
 \centering
 \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.49\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{1}
   \caption{1}
  \end{subfigure}\hfil
   \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.49\textwidth}
   \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{2}
  \caption{2}
  \end{subfigure}

   \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.49\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{3}
    \caption{3}
  \end{subfigure}\hfil
   \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.49\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{4}
    \caption{4}
 \end{subfigure}
\caption{blabla}
\end{widespace}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```